# how to select all monday/tuesday or any day through calendar after click on week name icon like: "M, T ...."

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, calendar

I want to select all Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday ...Sunday, through click on week day icon on calendar . I mean when I will click on Monday icon on calendar popup then all the Mondays should be selected correspond to current month.

Please suggest to me what should I do or is there any calendar API is available with such kind of functionality.

Right now I am using bootstrap-datepicker in Ruby on Rails application so please suggest to me suitable API or any gem.

Comment: Please show your code and effort you have taken to achieve your requirement. We will surely help you if you are getting any error not finding solution moving further..

Comment: I have only initialized the datepicker function like: 

$('#start_date, #end_date').datetimepicker({format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'})